# Anchor tag to root directory

Tags: html, directory, anchor, traversal

With my limited tech vocab I can't find a related question / answer to this question.

I'm working on a project that has some back buttons that need to traverse up 2–3 levels in my directory (which happens to be back to my root directory / home page). I have been using this `<a href="../../"></a>` or `<a href="../../../"></a>` depending on how many folders I needed to jump up.

In passing it was just suggested to me that I use `<a href="/"></a>` as this will send me straight back to my root directory / home page.

My question is are there any drawbacks to using this method?

I can see the benefits from a performance point of view, even if it is only a couple less characters, every little bit helps.

Thanks all who are prepared to clarify for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion I have confirmed there are no drawbacks with this method.

It's just an effective way of going straight back to your root folder should you need to.